# Is it possible to code a web app using more than 1 server-side scripting language?

Tags: php, python-2.7, web, server

Let's say I have a web app server coded in PHP, would it be possible to develop the app's server further using a different language (say, Python)?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You could write multiple web apps which act as one by sharing a consistent styling and structure and basically have links to each other's content/functionality.  Users won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible (and pretty common), but as for a "how do I do this?" that's far too broad to answer.

For an example, I built a game using PHP for the front end (using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)), and then behind the scenes it processes games using python (on top of [pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/)) and a few other bits and pieces.

Most low-cost web hosts will only provide one language that youw an work with (most commonly PHP), but if you run your own server you can run whatever you want to on there.